# iOS - Determine if coordinate is inside GMSPolyline

Tags: ios, google-maps

I am already using the method `GMSGeometryContainsLocation` in order to determine if the coordinate (from a tap user) is within GMSPolygon, but I can't make it work for GMSPolyline.

```
-(void) didTapOnPolyline:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate andMap:(GMSMapView *)mapView {
    if (_pathVS != nil) {
        for (id key in _pathVS) {
            if (GMSGeometryIsLocationOnPath(coordinate, [_pathVS objectForKey:key], YES)) {
                _myMarker = [GMSMarker markerWithPosition:coordinate];
                _myMarker.opacity = 1.f;
                // _myMarker.icon = [UIImage imageNamed:@"marker-maps"];

                _myMarker.map = mapView;
                _myMarker.userData = key;
                [_mapView setSelectedMarker:_myMarker];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am calling this method from the triggered delegate method :

```
-(void) mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView didTapAtCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate
{
    if (_myMarker)
        _myMarker.map = nil;

    [self didTapOnPolygon:coordinate andMap:mapView];
    [self didTapOnPolyline:coordinate andMap:mapView];
}
```

Comment: If your `didTapOnPolyline` delegate triggers then user is tapping on the `polyline` right? then why are check the point is on line or not?

Comment: This is my custom method. Look the edit

Comment: If the tapped point is not exactly on the poly line then it will not work. You can check the point is on or near to the poly line by using `GMSGeometryIsLocationOnPathTolerance`

Comment: Yes I was trying this, but I am wondering how tolerant I can be.

Comment: Its in meter. It will check the point is near the poly line radius (Radius value is your tolerance value)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the tapped point is not exactly on the poly line then `GMSGeometryIsLocationOnPath` condition will never return true. So you have to use `GMSGeometryIsLocationOnPathTolerance`

***Google Map SDK document says***

> > A point that is not equal to a vertex is on one side or the other of any path segment -- it can never be "exactly on the border"

```
BOOL GMSGeometryIsLocationOnPathTolerance (CLLocationCoordinate2D point, GMSPath *path, BOOL    geodesic, CLLocationDistance tolerance)
```

Returns whether point lies on or near path, within the specified tolerance in meters.

Comment: GMSGeometryIsLocationOnPathTolerance never return true .  can you help me .